# Split a string which is seperated by 2 literals as an object in Java

Tags: java, string, literals

Consider a string `"100,abc,20.00|101,def,10.00"`.in which each parameter is seperated by `,` and each object seperated by `|` .

I want to seperate it into individual objects like `[{"id":"100","name":"abc","price":"20.00"},{"id":"101","name":"def","price":"10.00"]`

using java

Comment: What specific issue have you run in to? Other than normal CSV woes it seems like even the simple solution should work fine.

Comment: I am able to split using split method by passing , as literal but unable to form the required object, looping using for each loop but unable to form required object

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to transform the string, you can use two for loops and a string builder:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] keys = new String[] {"id","name","price"};
    String input = "100,abc,20.00|101,def,10.00";
    String[] objectList = input.split("\\|");
    
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (String object : objectList) {
        String[] itemList = object.split(",");
        int i = 0;
        
        if (output.length() != 0)
            output.append("},{");
        
        StringBuilder outputObject = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (String item : itemList) {
            if (outputObject.length() != 0)
                outputObject.append(",");
        
            outputObject.append("\"" + keys[i] + "\":\"" + item + "\"");
            i++;
        }
        
        output.append(outputObject.toString());
    }
    output.insert(0, "{");
    output.append("}");
    
    System.out.println(output.toString());
    }
}
```